# Razor with devExpress pageControl

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, devexpress

I'm using devExpress 11.1 with MVC 3/razor and i'm experiencing problems with putting html tags into the content of the tabs of the pageControl e.g. I would like to put `<div id="someDiv"></div>` into the content.

Did anyone encounter similar problems?

Comment: please clarify issue you encountered and PageControl's definition

Comment: Thanks Mikhail, but i figured out the issue. I didn't knew that I had to write even the HTML tags in quoatation marks. I thought that was only for text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At present, you can follow recommendation from the "[Using in Razor Views](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument9944)" topic and wait a little when the "[Razor Demos](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/aspnet/archive/2011/07/14/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-demos-coming-soon-in-minor-release-v2011-vol-1-6.aspx)" will be available.

Answer (score 0):

ViewContext.Writer.Write() is used to write html tags inside contents. Just go through this example.

```
settings.SetContent(() =>
        {


            ViewContext.Writer.Write("<div class=accountHeader>");
            ViewContext.Writer.Write("<h2>");
            ViewContext.Writer.Write("Welcome to My Site");
            ViewContext.Writer.Write("</h2>");               
            ViewContext.Writer.Write("</p>");
            ViewContext.Writer.Write("</div>");

});
```